# why i can't add another entry to a mysql datatbase table

Tags: php, mysql

i'm diving into php and mysql and have a simple php scrip which tries to store planeID's and planeType's into a table called 'planes. When my table is completely empty, the script succeeds in inserting the planeID/planeType into the table. But afterwards i can't add a second entry.

here is what i have in my php file:

```
<?php
    require '../db/connect.php';

    $planeID = $_POST['planeID'];
    $planeType = $_POST['planeType'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `planes`
                (`planeType` , `planeID`)
            VALUES(
                " .$planeType. ",
                " .$planeID. "'
            )";
    mysql_query( $sql );
```

i don't get any error messages :/

Comment: Echo mysql_error () after your query and probably duplicate key.

Comment: Maybe unique index on a column. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: `mysql_query( $sql ) or die( mysql_error() );`

Comment: I think there should be a confirmation alert for users who want to post mysql error related problems stating, "What does your echo mysql_error() shows" or something like this. . .

Answer (score 1):

You where missing the single quotes around the values.

```
<?php
    require '../db/connect.php';

    $planeID = $_POST['planeID'];
    $planeType = $_POST['planeType'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `planes`
                (`planeType` , `planeID`)
            VALUES(
                '" .$planeType. "', <--
                '" .$planeID. "'    <--
            )";
    mysql_query( $sql );
```

Comment: Unless they happen to be integers.

Comment: well i see 1 closing single quote and not the other on the original post, but yes if they are ints then they are not needed

Comment: both are strings. but even after adding the single quotes, it does not work

Comment: @juleee then remove the single quote from here " .$planeID. "'

Comment: also try adding mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error()); to see if it throws an error

Comment: thanks to the mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error());
i could find out, that a primary key was existing twice and that was the problem :)